# xCode - Why this memory-leak?

Tags: xcode, memory-leaks, nsmutablearray

I have an NSMutableArray defined like this:

```
@property (nonatomic, retain)           NSMutableArray          *cList;
```

I have properly placed in my dealloc the release to cList, and in a selector I retrive some data from the database:

```
sqlite3 *database;

if(sqlite3_open([self.filePath UTF8String], &database) == SQLITE_OK) { 

    NSString *sqlStatement = [NSString stringWithFormat:@".....", self.someData];
    sqlite3_stmt *compiledStatement; 

    if (self.cList != nil) {
        [self.cList release];
        self.cList = nil;   
    }
    self.cList = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init]; 

    if(sqlite3_prepare_v2(database, [sqlStatement UTF8String], -1, &compiledStatement, NULL) == SQLITE_OK) { 
        sqlite3_bind_text(compiledStatement, 1, [self.someString UTF8String], -1, SQLITE_TRANSIENT);
        sqlite3_bind_text(compiledStatement, 2, [self.someOtherString UTF8String], -1, SQLITE_TRANSIENT);
        while(sqlite3_step(compiledStatement) == SQLITE_ROW) {
            MyModel *newM = [[MyModel alloc] init]; 
            newM.d  = [NSString stringWithUTF8String:(char *) sqlite3_column_text(compiledStatement, 0)];
            newM.c  = [NSString stringWithUTF8String:(char *) sqlite3_column_text(compiledStatement, 1)];
            newM.i  = [NSString stringWithUTF8String:(char *) sqlite3_column_text(compiledStatement, 2)];
            [self.cList addObject:newM];
            [newM release];
        }
    }
    sqlite3_finalize(compiledStatement);
}
sqlite3_close(database);
```

When I run with Instruments it shows me some leaks in this lines:

```
        self.cList = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init]; 
...
        MyModel *newM = [[MyModel alloc] init]; 
        newM.d  = [NSString stringWithUTF8String:(char *) sqlite3_column_text(compiledStatement, 0)];
        newM.c  = [NSString stringWithUTF8String:(char *) sqlite3_column_text(compiledStatement, 1)];
        newM.i  = [NSString stringWithUTF8String:(char *) sqlite3_column_text(compiledStatement, 2)];
        [self.cList addObject:newM];
```

with leaked objects: NSCFString and MyModel. Why? I have properly released cList object.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This block of code

```
if (self.cList != nil) {
    [self.cList release];
    self.cList = nil;   
}
self.cList = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
```

Can be replaced entirely by this:

```
self.cList = [NSMutableArray array];
```

That will eliminate the first leak. Not sure why you're getting a leak warning on the second block of code, since you are releasing `newM` properly.

---

The code leaks because you are creating an object and taking ownership of it (`[[NSMutableArray alloc] init]`) and then you are setting that object as a `retain` property, taking ownership of the object yet again. In theory, you could get around this by calling `release` twice, but that's silly. `[NSMutableArray array]` returns an autoreleased mutable array. By setting it to your `retain` property, you take ownership of it once.

Also, one other small point, there is no need to check to see if a your property is nil. If you want to remove a property, just do `self.cList = nil;`. The runtime will handle releasing the variable for you; that's one of the great reasons to use @properties.

Comment: Replacing like you said eliminated all the leaks. Thanks. But can you explain me why it was leaking?

Comment: The warning in the second block stems from the same root cause. Because newM is added to cList, it also leaks when cList leaks.

Answer (score 1):

The call to 'alloc' returns an owning (ie, +1) reference. When you assign it to a 'retain' property, you then increment the retain count, giving +2. Hence when you release it later, it leaks with a retain count of +1. Ditto when you add newM to cList, it gets retained again even though you already own it.

Suggested alterations:

```
    self.cList = [[[NSMutableArray alloc] init] autorelease];  // or [NSMutableArray array]
    ...
    MyModel *newM = [[[MyModel alloc] init] autorelease]; 
    newM.d  = [NSString stringWithUTF8String:(char *) sqlite3_column_text(compiledStatement, 0)];
    newM.c  = [NSString stringWithUTF8String:(char *) sqlite3_column_text(compiledStatement, 1)];
    newM.i  = [NSString stringWithUTF8String:(char *) sqlite3_column_text(compiledStatement, 2)];
    [self.cList addObject:newM];
```

So in both cases you're using autorelease to say that the objects should be released automatically in the future if you don't otherwise retain them — which you do by virtue of the (retain) property and by adding to an NSArray.

Comment: I didn't tested yet, but doing like you said: self.cList = [[[NSMutableArray alloc] init] autorelease]; wouldn't release my cList let's say at the end of the selector? And would it be possible to use it later, in my app?

Comment: cList would be released once by the autorelease pool, when you get back into the run loop. But you've done the same thing as retaining it twice - once due to the 'alloc', once due to the 'retain' property. The Objective-C dot syntax calls the setter, even though it looks like a C-style struct member value assignment. And two retains + one release = correct ownership count.